# Why can I multiply a constant to a first derivative to get the second derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

**Sample question**

given that $\frac{dW}{dt}=\frac{1}{25}(W-300)$

what is the $\frac{dW^2}{d^2t}$?

**Textbook answer**

The textbook said that we can multiple $\frac{1}{25}$ to the first derivative to find the second derivative but I thought that the answer was just to take the derivative of the first derivative.

How can the textbook be right?

Comment: The textbook is right *in this case* **because** $W$ is the solution of a first order linear ODE.

Comment: Differentiate both sides of the first equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ \dfrac{d^2W}{dt^2}  = \dfrac{d}{dt}\left(\dfrac{dW}{dt}\right) = \dfrac{d}{dt}\left(\dfrac{1}{25}(W-300)\right) = \dfrac{1}{25}\dfrac{dW}{dt} - \dfrac{1}{25}\dfrac{d 300}{dt} = \dfrac{1}{25}\left(\dfrac{1}{25}(W-300)\right).$$

Comment: Edit: first line $$\frac{d^2 W}{d t^2}$$